# Angular: How dynamcally change scss variables?

Tags: angular, sass, scss-mixins

Im new to scss so I was wondering if I can change scss variables using the Typescript of a component for example.

So consider this:

```
html: 
<div (someEvent)="handleEvent($event)"></div>

scss: 
$thememode: 'theme1'; 
$textcolormode: 'nonHover'; 
$colorOpacity: 0.1; 
@mixin someFunction(param1, param2){
    //do scss magic
}

ts: //Here is what I want to do, but dont know to code:
handleEvent(event):void{
   this.scssFile.$thememode = 'theme2'; 
   this.scssFile.$colormode = 'hover'; 
   this.scssFile.$colorOpacity = this.someattribute + this.someServive.$generateAnotherValue(someParam); 
   this.scssFile.@someFunction(23, 'mode1'); 
}
```

Basically I just want to be able to access the scss variables/mixins I define.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Just use CSS variables.

Answer (score 2):

Manipulating Sass files from your Angular Component is not possible since at the time Angular accesses your Component, Sass is already compiled to CSS.
You should use the [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) and [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directives to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Scss is a preprocessor. Is it transformed into regular CSS at compile time. Which means that you can't modify your Scss during runtime as it doesn't exist anymore.

An alternative way to manage your theming dynamically would be to use [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and update them dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

As some others already mentioned, a good way is to use CSS variables. Even if you have to support IE11 this is fine, as there's a ponyfill that works for this. Please note that you can also mix the usage of SCSS and CSS properties, just define some CSS properties and use them in your SCSS definitions, the generated CSS will still contain the CSS properties.

I use the very same approach in a project of mine, where I parse some colors values from a configuration file at runtime, and then set the css properties according to those values:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const options: any = {
      watch: true,
      preserveStatic: false,
      variables: {
        '--accent': AppConfigService.settings.style.accent,
        '--contrast': AppConfigService.settings.style.contrast,
        '--page-color': AppConfigService.settings.style.pagecolor,
        '--page-contrast': AppConfigService.settings.style.pagecontrast,
        '--text-color': AppConfigService.settings.style.textcolor,
        '--info-color': AppConfigService.settings.style.infocolor,
        '--warn-color': AppConfigService.settings.style.warncolor,
        '--white': AppConfigService.settings.style.white
      }
    };
    cssVars(options);
  }
```

The mentioned ponyfill is *css-vars-ponyfill*