# Is it actually possible to edit Bootstrap scss variables after the application is compiled?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I hope my question is not too vague. The problem is, my project was created with Angular and I'm using Bootstrap for styling. At the moment I'm correctly overriding Bootstrap variables with my custom-variables.scss file. This way I can set a different primary color for every HTML element:

`$theme-colors: ("primary": #C7201F);`

What I'd like to achieve is being able to change this color with, for example, a Angular service, swapping the color itself with a variable (theme change feature) but I'm having a hard time trying to find a solution to this problem. I'm not a skilled programmer and first I must understand if this thing is possible.

Being able to change the color of the primary variable seems the best solution to create a color-switching theme without the need to manually override `.btn` and `.btn-primary` classes from css, which I don't think is a optimal solution since there are many properties behind a button styling in bootstrap.

The color-swapping feature must be visible while the application is running so I'm afraid it's not possible... Anyway, I'm open to different solutions if you are willing to help, thanks.

Comment: All SCSS stuff gets preprocessed, which means that when your application is running you don't have the `$theme-colors` variable available in any place.

I'd say one idea might be pre-cook all your themes and then dynamically load the desired CSS when the application starts. 

This way a "switch theme" button would set a variable in your localstorage that indicates the theme you want, it would then refresh your application which, in your app-component, would load the desidered style using the DomSanitizer so Angular doesn't complain

You could even just load the css in your index.html

Comment: Maybe this question would help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322452/angular-how-dynamcally-change-scss-variables